# How can I search a JTextPane for a certain formatting?

Tags: java, swing, rtf, jtextpane

I have had a problem with saving a `JTextPane` as an RTF. The alignment is not saved.

If I can search the `JTextPane` for center alignment before I save it, and add in a tag, such as, say *center*, then upon document open, I could set the paragraph formatting appropiately.

How can I search the `JTextPane` for center/right text alignment?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 3):

Get your `Document` and cast it to a `DefaultStyledDocument`. Then use the `getParagraphElement()` method to get the offset from the start of the paragraph. Check the alignment of the paragraph `StyleConstants.getAlignment()` and pass the attributes of the paragraph `Element`. Then use the end offset of the paragraph to get the next one.